# not able to convert \ format java.util.Date to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, date, java-8, java.util.date

I am trying to convert java.util.Date to java.util.Date but in different format

> Wed Oct 11 10:00:00 CDT 2023 -->
> 2023-10-11T10:00:00.000Z

I show lot of post and also tried different solutions below but no luck.

converted Date to String and again into Date but format doesn't change.

```
  Date utilDate = Wed Oct 11 10:00:00 CDT 2023 // Your java.util.Date

        // Define the desired format
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        // Convert the java.util.Date to a formatted String
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(utilDate);

        System.out.println("Formatted Date String: " + formattedDate);
//convert String again into java.util.Date
// it will return the same utilDate.
```

Also tried with 2 SimpleDateFormat object. Please guide me further.

Comment: "I am trying to convert java.util.Date to java.util.Date but in different format" - a java.util.Date doesn't *have* a format. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: (Fundamentally, it's important to know that types like this don't have a format, any more than an `int` has a notion of whether it's hex or decimal. It's just a number. I'd *also* encourage you to use java.time though...)

Comment: You certainly mean you want to print the very same `Date` in two different formats, don't you?

Comment: The first format is the default one from `Date.toString()` and the second one is your desired format, but you are missing things in it, e.g. the offset from UTC and the `'T'` separating date from time.

Comment: If you are using at least Java 8, then see this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: You say you want a format like `2023-10-11T10:00:00.000Z`.  But your SimpleDateFormat contains neither a `T` nor a `Z` nor a timezone specifier.  So which format do you really want?  (Regardless, you should use the java.time package as everyone else has suggested.)

Comment: Your code is correct, first parse the value, and then format it with another _SimpleDateFormat_.  You'll need to append the _Z_.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for your date and time work and skip the old and poorly designed classes like `Date` and `SimpleDatFormat` completely. Use `String formattedDate = utilDate.toInstant().toString();` the others are correct, though, you are asking the impossible since a `Date` cannot have a format.

Comment: CDT means Cuba daylight time (or Chatham or Central). `Z` means UTC. They are not the same. Please confirm that you want to retain the time of day, 10:00:00, thereby changing into a different point in time?

Comment: The solution is to switch to java.time, and we are in the process of upgrading to the java.time package. Thank you all. I kindly request that we avoid giving negative points, as we can instead guide individuals toward the correct solution. This will prevent discouraging people, and they may be more inclined to ask questions again.

Answer (score 7):

1. `java.util.Date` is a lie. It does not represent dates. It represents moments in time, without a timezone. There's a reason almost every method on Date (such as `.getYear()`) is deprecated: It is **not possible** to ask an instant in time 'what year is that'. Not without involving timezones at the very least.
2. Date objects don't have a format. They contain, literally, 1 `long` field with epoch millis. Instead, anytime you want to turn a date into, say, pixels on a screen (e.g. you try to toss one at `System.out.println`, or `jLabel.setText(dateHere)`, or toss it in a template context object which is then used to render an HTML template), you choose, *every time*, **how** to turn this wrapper-around-epochmillis-with-a-silly-name into those pixels / characters. There is **no way** to modify how Date's `toString()` implementation renders it, and in general `toString()` is solely to be used as a debugging aid, **never** as part of your business logic (that soup isn't consumed quite as hot as I just put it, but especially if you're inexperienced or new to java, that's the rule of thumb to adhere to until you've gotten much more experience).

Hence, there is no direct answer available to your question because your question's specifics do not make any sense. It's like asking: "How do I paint my walls with the colour 'fish'. Which screwdriver should I use?" - a series of non-sequiturs.

But the spirit is obvious enough.

Thus:

1. Use `java.time`. Stop using `java.util.Date`. If you're forced into it, because a thing you do not directly control provides it to you, then double check that there isn't a better way (example: If using JDBC to talk to a database, don't call `.getDate(colIdx)`. Call `.getObject(colIdx, LocalDate.class)`). If there really isn't treat it the same way you treat any broken code you are forced to work with: Wrap it with a 'cleaner' - ensure that the bad thing doesn't infect your code base. Write a method that takes that `j.u.Date` from the external thing you cannot change and modifies it immediatly to whatever is actually appropriate here (could be `LocalDate`, could be `ZonedDateTime`, could be `Instant` - without you explaining what this is for, there is no way to know. Date/time reckoning is far too complex for a 'one type covers all needs' solution).
2. Use `DateTimeFormatter` (java.time's version of SimpleDateFormat).
3. If you need to convert reckoning, do not go via formatting and parsing. Formatting and parsing is for just that - to transfer a concept of some point in time from human fingers to computers and from computers to human eyeballs. `java.time` objects have ways to go from one to the other. Have a `LocalDateTime` and need to make that a zoned thing? There are methods on LDTs to make ZDTs out of them. Their parameters guide you in this process (For example, to do that, you will need to specify a time zone). Do you need to convert from one zone to another? Take your LDT, convert it to a ZDT, convert that to a ZDT in a different zone, convert that back to an LDT.